# How to convert a string value to float value

Tags: string, floating-point

I have these quantities and i want to transform it to a float variable, but i have to quit the letter at the end, I tried like the next code:

```
A=6574.6A
B=977.020A     
C=1085.00A  
D=33.133A
s=float(A)
print(s)
```

But it doesn't work, because I have a until the end. How could I remove the letter and just have the numeric value? I can't remove it manually because I have a huge list of values.

Comment: What language?  Python?

Comment: Yes, is in python

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  If there is always one letter at the end, `s = float(A[:-1])`.